# Confused by Symfony Upload Documentation

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to follow the [Symfony 2.1 documentation for handling uploads](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) and I am confused about where one of the variables in their code is comes from.

Where does the $this->file variable come from in there upload method?

**Symfony Upload Method:**

```
public function upload()
{
    // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }

    // use the original file name here but you should
    // sanitize it at least to avoid any security issues

    // move takes the target directory and then the
    // target filename to move to
    $this->file->move(
        $this->getUploadRootDir(),
        $this->file->getClientOriginalName()
    );

   // set the path property to the filename where you've saved the file
    $this->path = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();

    // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
    $this->file = null;
}
```

Because the Document entity that the describe earlier in the documentation only has three variables which are id, name and path

**Symfony Entity:**

```
 /**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Document
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $path;
}
```

Have I misunderstood?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it's the value of the `file` input field in the form

Comment: Read through the article again, it's stated there. Hint: the second code example and below.

Comment: @lazyhammer yep you are right. The third code example was on the YAML tab and when I flipped it to the Annotations tab it made more sense. Thanks alot.